# Styles does not load if the navigation stays the same JSF page

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, styles, rendering

I have a command button which i bind its action method.

```
<f:view >
    <pm:page title="Title">
        <pm:view id="viewId" swatch="c">
            <p:outputPanel id="panelId">
                <h:form id="formId">   

    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.actionMethod}" update="formId" value="Click" />
                           </h:form>
                     </p:outputPanel>
               </pm:view>
    </pm:page >
</f:view>
```

Inside action method. the navigation refers the same page. Some values are updated inside action method.

```
public String applyPeriod(String caller)
{
    .....
    retrun SAMEPAGE;
}
```

Every thing is ok. but the styles is not rendered. the page returns to the default styles.

Any idea how i can load the styles. I do not want to change URL by doing real refresh. i should managed it by ajax calls.

I trace the requests of the page. There is exactly no call for styles.

I use primefaces, primefaces mobile and it is a mobile page.

Comment: In case your managed bean get re-initialized, check if your bean's properties also get re-initialized to some default value.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/ your current update client ID is looking for `<x:someComponent id="formId">` **inside** the form, it's not referring the form itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't use `:` behind your form's ID I believe the problem can be related to a relative component search, trying to finding the form based on a relative identifier. By using the different element's ID you're getting the expected behaviour, I pressume because they're correctly referenced in a relative way to the context of your `<p:commandButton/>`.

Try using either `update="@form"` or `update=":formId"`. Also, as a side note, if you want to use full ajax and you won't be redirecting the user anywhere, your method should either be `void` or return `null`.

Comment: detailed BalusC answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know the reason behind the scenes. However, i solved the issue by giving exact components ids to update attributes of commandButton.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.actionMethod}" update="ListOfComponentIds" value="Click" />
```